# Update UI when application runs in backroud

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a banking application for Windows Phone 8.1 RT. For security reason I need to grey out or show an image in my application when it goes background.

It's like when application is running user presses windows button then press and hold back button at that time application's current page is visible. I need to show a image on that view.

When application is running if user press and hold back button at that time also irrespective of page I need to grey my application or show an image.

I have tried changing the opacity of frame in On suspending event it is not reflecting. I have also tried in Window visibility changed event changing the opacity of Window.Content but it's not working too.

Please help me with some pointers on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way to do this. The app doesn't suspend until several seconds after it has left the screen, so it is too late for the app to change its UI then. Window.Activated would be closer, but is still too late.

ApplicationView.IsScreenCaptureEnabled will prevent capturing a screenshot of the page either in the app or on the task switcher page, but won't prevent the image from showing at all.

The least bad may be to call Application.Current.Exit to close the application completely when deactivated. This is generally a user unfriendly idea, but it will remove the app from the task switcher one it closes (it will probably show up briefly first though).

You can post feature requests on http://wpdev.uservoice.com